# Yamaha FZ6 S2 - dead after key duplication

Tags: yamaha, ignition-key, immobilizer

I've only had my used 08 bike for a week - first bike. It came with only a master key which I used to ride 2 days ago and I left the ignition in lock position. Today I had a copy made in the local hardware place. They ordered a blank, cut the key and copied the transponder codes. Tonight I tried it in the ignition, It unlocked the barrel but after that the bike was dead. Then I tried the master key. Still dead. I'm planning on getting the breakdown out tomorrow but I'm wondering - is it possible the duplicated key can have somehow blown the bike immobiliser system so is gone into lock down of some kind ? Or think it's pure coincidence and most likely battery/fuse? very worried I've screwed something.
 Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you actually checked the battery for power? That could be a big first step in diagnosis.

Comment: On most Japanese bikes, there is a second lock position that switches lights on, just after the normal lock position. If you did this, you probably emptied the battery, so like @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 says I would start by checking the battery voltage.

Answer (score -1):

Hiya yeah thanks I think I must've cranked the barrel all the way to the P position.  After leaving the battery to charge overnight I'm back up and running. Plus the new key works to boot!